# Build a python file using Sublime Text 2 in an external terminal

Tags: python, build, terminal, sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime Text 2 to write python program and I want to build it in an external terminal window.

The reason for this is I love terminal window(although I'm very new to coding world) and I can't input value in the integrated build result window in Sublime Text 2.

I've tried modify the python.sublime-build file and it looks like this:

```
{
  "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
  "shell": true}
```

Sadly no terminal window pops out after I hit build button. Result window only shows [Finished in 0.0s]. I can build without problem if I delete line "shell": true. Program runs fine.

I'm using OS X 10.9. Please help me to fix this build file. Thanks in advance.

---

In addition, since I'm new to coding, what knowledge do I need if I want to understand what's going on in all these configuration JSON files? Questions like:

```
What's the mechanism behind all this lines in setting files? 
Who's actually performing these commands, sublime text or the OS itself?
Does other software works in the same way as sublimate text does?
```

This maybe an irrelevant question but I'm very curious. Please suggest me if there's better place to put this question :D

Comment: Don't know if you that you've solved it yet. I ran into the very similar problem and I want Sublime to open Python console as well, not pull result to its output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plug-in: [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) At least it seems to be the workaround that suits your need. After running a script, you can examine the variables, the results, etc. Once you've install this (via `package control`), to use it go to Tools>sublimerepl>python from the menus. Evaluate your code from the REPL tab.

[Trival] Or try to code in Notepad++, if you're on Windows. Go to Plug-in manager, and install **PyNPP** plugin. This plugin allows you to run python file by calling Python console right from Notepad++. I'm familiar with the command "Alt + Shift + F5" for quite sometime before moving to ST. An interactive python console will pop up and stay there after you finish the script. This is exactly what you expect your ST to do in your question.

Since you're using MacOSX, and for the love of SublimeText (as my case), we stick with Sublime Text.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same - found it here, and it worked for me

[How to Show Build Results in OSX Terminal from Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462566/how-to-show-build-results-in-osx-terminal-from-sublime-text-2?rq=1)

The little hiccup I didn't write the full path to the script properly, the following worked for me. Read the link above and then have a look at my syntax. Doing something similar shoudl work for you!

```
{
"cmd": ["sh /Users/InNov8/Dropbox/Code/^sublimeRunFile.sh \"$file\""],
"shell": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat working solution;

```
{
  "path": "/usr/bin",
  "cmd": ["xfce4-terminal -e 'bash -c \"python -u $file;read RAHUL;\"'"],
  "shell": true,
  "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
  "working_dir": "${file_path}",
  "selector": "source.python"    
}
```

You can write your terminal name in place of "xfce4-terminal".